# Animation inside Block in hidden state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does animation work if the block content is in state "none"?

For example, if I want to use Load with JQuery, and I want animation to start after the page load, will this work?

```
.container {
display : none;
}
.container .animate {
transform : translate(0,-100px);
    transition : 1s transform ;
}
.show {
display : block ;

}
```

in jquery

```
$(function() {
          $(".container").addClass("show");
        });
```

If there is another way please help me.

Comment: the transition will take place at page load not on addclass event

Comment: If I wanted to know that, I'd build a quick test in a fiddle or a codepen.

Comment: @JeremyThille I have a lot of tests I'm ask if it's professional and a good way to did that, thank you

Comment: @madalinivascu that's mean the transition will take place before page load ?

Comment: May we see your tests?

Comment: Yes , wait I will copy my code to Fiddle

Comment: @JeremyThille Work only in FirFox because I didn't add Prefix  https://jsfiddle.net/n5s6q8ss/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `display:none` elements can be animated...

Here's a test : the text is hidden, translates to the right, then shows up : it works.

```js
$("p").addClass("shift");

setTimeout( function(){
    $("p").css("display","block");
}, 1000)
```

```css
p{
    display:none;
    border:green solid 1px;
    width:150px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

p.shift{
     transform : translate(300px,0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(300px,0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>some text</p>
```

Is this what you want?

Answer (score -1):

Just try to change the attr

```
$(function() {
    $(".container").attr("display","block !important");
});
```